# React Navigation, Remove the tab menu on the detail page

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am applying "A StackNavigator for each tab" described in the current Navigation Official Document.

URL : https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation.html#a-stacknavigator-for-each-tab

When you click the button in `Home Tabs -> Go to Home Details`, when you click the button in `Setting Tabs -> Go to Setting Details` You are finished.

Here, I want to change the code slightly so that the Tabs Menu is not visible in Details. How can I change this code?

```
const HomeStack = new StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    HomeDetails: { screen: HomeDetailsScreen }
});

const SettingStack = new StackNavigator({
    Setting: { screen: SettingScreen },
    SettingDetails: { screen: SettingDetailsScreen }
});

const AppStackTabNavigator = new TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Setting: { screen: SettingStack }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SettingDetailsScreen extends React.Component { 
   static navigationOptions = { 
      tabBarVisible: false,
    }
   // ...rest of code
}
```

If your `SettingDetailsScreen` is a functional component, then add this after the component declaration:

```
SettingDetailsScreen.navigationOptions = { tabBarVisible: false };
```

Comment: thanks. Yet... I could not solve it. But I found another way.
`const MainStack = new TabNavigator({  
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },  
    Setting: { screen: SettingScreen }  
});  
  
const AppStackTabNavigator = new StackNavigator({  
    Main: { screen: MainStack },  
    HomeDetails: { screen: HomeDetailsScreen },  
    SettingDetails: { screen: SettingDetailsScreen }  
}`

Comment: Sorry How to insert code "in Comment", I don't know;;

Comment: Wow. Thanks you. ^^